# How to obtain the collective outputs from multiple chains and consolidating them into the final output in LCEL?

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

I'm currently developing a Q&A chatbot using multiple chains, and my objective is to include the output generated in the middle chain directly into the final output. I'm uncertain about the steps to achieve this. Any guidance would be appreciated. below is my code.

```
standalone_chain = standalone_prompt | llm_chat | StrOutputParser()
answer_chain = (
    {
        "context": itemgetter("question") | vs.as_retriever(),
        "question": itemgetter("question"),
    }
    | answer_prompt
    | llm_chat.bind(functions=functions, function_call={"name": "answer"})
    | JsonOutputFunctionsParser()
)
format_chain = format_prompt | llm_chat
```

I am stuck with no clue.